# Prestashop user registration required fields

Tags: input, smarty, registration, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to get rid of two required fields in prestashop's v1.5 user registration. 
I want to set FirstName and LastName to not required.

To do so I removed the 'required' => true from both classes Address.php and Customer.php

But when I try to register I get the error: An error occurred while creating your account.

Any ideas why this happens?

Here's my Customer.php code:

```
public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'customer',
    'primary' => 'id_customer',
    'fields' => array(
        'secure_key' =>                 array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isMd5', 'copy_post' => false),
        'lastname' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'size' => 32),
        'firstname' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'size' => 32),
        'email' =>                      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isEmail', 'required' => true, 'size' => 128),
        'passwd' =>                     array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isPasswd', 'required' => true, 'size' => 32),
```

As you can see from the code it has only email and password fields set as required.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the required => false ?

```
'lastname' =>                   array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 32),
'firstname' =>                  array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isName', 'required' => false, 'size' => 32),
```